# Cambiar datos de envío de radio a button por medio de Ajax y jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estoy enviando datos por `<input type="radio">` a la base de datos, pero debo enviarlo por un `<input type="button">`.

Necesito que las personas que vean la página elijan una de las 5 opciones que tiene de respuesta y **solamente cuando le den "terminar" le suba la respuesta**

En éste momento lo tengo que al oprimir el campo del radio, ya sube el dato y no deja cambiar la opción.

Aquí el código.

**example.php**

```
function responder(){
        $(function(){
            $('button').click(function() {
                $('button').prop("disabled", true);
                valor= $(this).val();
                /*Desde aquí se invoca la función que agrega a la BD
                  y se pasa el valor del radio seleccionado*/
                agregarDatos(valor);
                console.log("Aquí se envía a la base de datos el valor de : "+valor); 
            });

        function agregarDatos(valor)
            {
            /*Desde esta función se puede implementar una llamada a Ajax 
                que enviará la información del radio seleccionado a la BD*/ 

            /*La petición Ajax sería algo así*/ 
            usuario= '<?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]; ?>'; 
            datos={usuario: usuario, respuesta: valor}; 
            console.log(datos); 

            /*comentado temporalmente*/
            var request = $.ajax({ 
                url: "subir.php", //Archivo de servidor que inserta en la BD 
                method: "POST", 
                data: datos, 
                dataType: "json" 
            }); 
            }
        });
     }
```

La tabla

```
<?php
    echo '<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Quien descubrió américa.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cristobal Colon: <br></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="p1" name="n1" value="Opción 1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Messi: <br></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="p1" name="n1" value="Opción 1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>El papa Francisco: <br></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="p1" name="n1" value="Opción 1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td aling="center"><button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="responder();"><h4>RESPONDER</h4></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>';
?>
```

**subir.php**

```
<?php 

//Verificar que estén todos los datos
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['respuesta']) && !empty($_POST['respuesta'])) 
    {
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $respuesta = $_POST['respuesta'];

    //Datos de conexión a la base de datos
    $host       = "localhost";
    $usuario_bd = "root";
    $clave      = "";
    $basedatos  = "evaluacion";
    $tabla      = "pregunta";

    //Conectar a la base
    //La variable $myslqi contendrá el objeto con la conexión
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario_bd, $clave, $basedatos);

    //Verificar si la conexión se realizó
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) 
        {
        $error="Error al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        $json=array(1=>$error);
        }

    //insert en la base
    $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, respuesta) VALUES (?, ?)");


    //Verificar si la sentencia se preparó
    if ($sentencia)
        {
        $sentencia->bind_param("ss", $respuesta, $usuario);
        $sentencia->execute();

        //Verificar si se insertaron datos
        if ($sentencia->affected_rows)
            {
            $json=array(2=>$sentencia->affected_rows);              
            }
            else
                {
                $json=array(3=>"Ningún dato insertado");
                }

        // Cerrar la $sentencia
        $sentencia = null;

        }
        else
            {
            $json=array(4=>"Error en la instrucción SQL");
            }

    //Cerrar la conexión
    $mysqli = null;

    }//end isset
    else
        {
        $json=array(5=>"La petición ajax no envió los datos correctamente");    
        }

//Respuesta que manejará la petición Ajax en examen.php
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: "En éste momento lo tengo que al oprimir el campo del radio, ya sube el dato y no deja cambiar la opción". Puedes explicarlo un poco mas claro? No entendi.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que la información se guarde en la BD cuando se presiona el boton en vez de cuando se selecciona el radio?

Comment: @Kenny si, eso es lo que quiero, que registre la respuesta sólo cuando le de en el botón.

Comment: @Einer cuando le da clic a una de las 5 opciones, se inhabilitan las demás, ejemplo, elije la opción 3 y luego quiere cambiarla a la 5, ya no se deja modificar... Y desde que le dé click ya sube el dato a la BD... Entonces quiero que si la persona se equivoca, pueda modificar la respuesta, pero que si le da al botón, ya no haya nada para hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te puede servir:

1. Desactivamos el botón al inicio
2. Obligamos a una sola opción de selección
3. Al seleccionar activamos el botón
4. Al hacer click en el botón llamamos la función `agregarDatos()` y obtenemos en ella el valor del radio seleccionado. Entonces desactivamos todo para que no sea posible enviar de nuevo.

```js
$(function() {
  boton = $("#btnResponder");
  boton.prop("disabled", true);

  $(':radio').click(function() {
    boton.prop("disabled", false);

    //Obligamos a que no se pueda seleccionar más de un radio
    if (this.checked) {
      $('[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});

function agregarDatos() {
  //Obtenemos el valor del radio seleccionado
  var valor = $("input[name='n1']:checked").val();
  console.log(valor);

  //Desactivamos para que ya no sea posible enviar
  boton.prop("disabled", true);
  $(':radio').prop("disabled", true);

//Resto del código

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Quien descubrió américa.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cristobal Colon: <br></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="p1" name="n1" value="Opción 1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Messi: <br></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="p2" name="n1" value="Opción 2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>El papa Francisco: <br></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="p3" name="n1" value="Opción 3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td aling="center"><button id="btnResponder" class="btn btn-success" onclick="agregarDatos();"><h4>RESPONDER</h4></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Cambios con respecto a tu código

- He corregido el HTML, ya que los radio tenían el mismo id, esta etiqueta debe ser única para cada elemento HTML.
- En el `button` he agregado el `onclick` que llama a la función `agregarDatos();`
- La función `agregarDatos()` queda ahora fuera de este bloque: `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: ¿Y en el **agregar.php** no cambia nada?

Comment: @CarlosOrtiz no, `agregar.php` recibirá lo que tú le envías vía Ajax mediante la función `agregarDatos()`. Otra cosa, he corregido el HTML, ya que los radio tenían el mismo `id`, esta etiqueta debe ser única para cada elemento HTML. También en el `button` he agregado el `onclick` que llama a la función `agregarDatos()`;

Comment: En este caso no altera nada, porque en realidad no estás tratando de alcanzar nada usando el id vía jQuery. Lo importante es saber que no es buena práctica tener dos elementos con el mismo id en un documento (es como si existiesen dos personas con el mismo documento de identidad) y que los ids deben ser descriptivos, que cuando los veas sepas a que hacen referencia.

Comment: Ah listo, y falta algo, después del botón **responder** no se debe quedar inactivo si no que lo debe redireccionar al menú... yo lo activé, más no sé cómo hacer para que se vaya a `menu_principal.php`. Yo lo hice así, no sé qué tan bién esté: `boton.prop("enabled", true).load("menu_principal.php")`, lo intento pero no me carga

Comment: No le veo sentido a activar el botón si vas a redireccionar a otra página. Redireccionar significa que saldrás de la página actual. Lo puedes hacer con esto: `window.location.href='menu_principal.php';`

Comment: ¿Y en dónde pongo el window.location?

Comment: Cuando hagas todo lo que tienes que hacer en la función `agregarDatos()`. Si por ejemplo quieres enviar la respuesta a la base de datos, pondrías el window.location dentro del `done`  de la llamada Ajax.